# how to access specific column values from a column of multiple values in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can i access single values from genre column
data[data['Genre']=='Action'] whenever i use this it only fetch me values with Action coulmn the colum which contains Action , SiFi it does not fetch it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JeGf.png)

Comment: I would convert the column to a list first, then use `pd.explode`.  What you are then trying will work.

Comment: Otherwise, use `data[data['Genre'].str.contains("Action")`

Comment: Great!  Which one?

Comment: I tried 2 one..

Answer (score 1):

Moving my comment to an answer, so that the question can be marked as "answered".

```
data[data['Genre'].str.contains("Action")
```

Using `==` means "is exactly equal to".  Therefore, it would not return anything that contains Action, but only those which ***are*** Action.